# Where are dynamicFields created in solr

Tags: solr

In my schema.xml

```
<dynamicField name="attributes_*" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<dynamicField name="itemAttributes_*" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
```

after I insert the record with dynamic fields then , where these fields are created on disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema is "only" used for validation / querying / etc. by Solr, meaning that the content is compared (and field types applied) to the schema when a field is being queried (to get the field type and analysis chain) or when it's being inserted. The schema is a Solr concept, while Lucene is the thing that makes Solr work behind the scenes.

Since the actual storage of data is not connected to the schema, and a Lucene document is a collection of field names and associated values, the field name doesn't have to exist in the schema to be stored in a Lucene document - just for Solr to accept it for storage into its Lucene index.

The fields are created in the index in the same way as any field explicitly named in the index.